# Word Automation using microsoft word interop for a web application without an Interactive User

Tags: c#, .net, com, office-interop

I am aware that Microsoft does not recommend using word automation on server side ([link to considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)).

Still I see some advantages of using word automation such as the ability to use a template and allow my client to change it (the plain text) with no need to change any coding.

My problem: I couldn't find a way to execute the word automation function when there is no interactive user (I am using a virtual dedicated server and I have to use remote connection). If I don't connect to the server the word automation doesn't work.

I read what I could find on this topic, and I would like to share the way I managed to sort this problem out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solution applies when the Word Automation works when there is an interactive user. the steps hereunder are to change from interactive user to a specific user so there is not obligation to be connected to the server to allow the word automation to work.

1. I created a new User on the server set a password and give it Administrator privileges.
2. Click Start, click Run, and then type DCOMCNFG.
3. in Component Services->Computers->My Computer ->DCOM config ==> right click Microsoft Word 97-2003. select Properties.
4. in Security tab go to Edit and Add the user you created.
5. in Identity select "This user" put the user you created and password.

I hope some of you will find it helpful.

Comment: In my case there is no Microsoft Word listed.. What should i do..?

Comment: Do you have office installed on your machine?

Comment: oo..yes.. and i figured out that i was running on 64 bit machine so.. i had to had to run 'mmc-32' and select 'component services' in File>Add Snaps In. And there it was..